# Can python segmentation fault be caused due to limited memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, segmentation-fault

Today I was solving  question on Hacker-Rank called  : Candies.
I tried a recursive algorithm.
All the test cases passed except one. Which showed a runtime error. So I downloaded the input file and ran it on my code.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000)

# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

class Node :

    def __init__(self,imp):

        self.value = 0
        self.imp = imp
        self.left = self.right = None

    def get_val(self) :
        #print self.imp
        if self.value != 0 :
            return

        if not self.right and not self.left :
            self.value = 1
            return

        if not self.left :

            if self.right.imp >= self.imp :

                self.value = 1

            else :

                self.right.get_val()
                self.value = self.right.value + 1
            return

        if not self.right :
            if self.left.imp >= self.imp :
                self.value = 1
            else :
                self.value = self.left.value + 1

            return

        else :
            if self.left.imp == self.imp :
                if self.right.imp >= self.imp :
                    self.value = 1

                else :
                    self.right.get_val()
                    self.value = self.right.value + 1

            elif self.right.imp == self.imp :
                if self.left.imp > self.imp :
                    self.value =1 
                else :
                    self.value = self.left.value +1

            elif self.left.imp > self.imp <self.right.imp :
                self.value = 1
            elif self.left.imp < self.imp <self.right.imp :
                self.value = self.left.value +1

            elif self.left.imp > self.imp  >self.right.imp :
                self.right.get_val()
                self.value = self.right.value +1
            elif self.left.imp < self.imp  > self.right.imp :
                self.right.get_val()
                if self.left.value > self.right.value :
                    self.value = self.left.value +1
                else :
                    self.value = self.right.value +1





with open("input",'r') as textfile :
    a = int(textfile.readline().strip())
    start = Node(int(textfile.readline().strip()))

    temp1 = start

    for i in range(a -1 ) :
        temp = Node(int(textfile.readline().strip()))
        temp1.right = temp
        temp.left = temp1
        temp1 = temp

temp1 = start

for i in range(a) :
    print temp1.imp,i
    temp1.get_val()

    temp1 = temp1.right

print "done"
temp1 = start
toffee = 0
for i in range (a) :
    #print temp1.value
    toffee += temp1.value


    temp1 = temp1.right



print toffee
```

The input file had the first entry as 100000 and then followed by 100000 no.s from 1 to 100,000.
When I first ran the input file from my PC it gave maximum recursion dept error. So I added the code on top making the recursion limit to 100000 as that would've been the maximum recursion depth my program woud've taken if it ran completely. But the I encountered this error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

To see exactly where this was happening I added the print statement commented out in the code at line 10 (Which would basically tell where the recursive call was at that point). The output was a series of no.s from 100000 to 75064
then came the segmentation fault.

Bird's eye view of algorithm is Node(100000).get_val() will call Node(99999).get_val() which will in turn call Node(99998).get_val() and so on..

Hence my guess is after 100000 - 75064 calls memory limit is reached and it cant make any more Nodes and hence calls segmentation fault. But I read that python has no memory upper limit. So why is this happening ??!!

Ps. I can improve a lot upon my code to make it faster and take up less memory but this was the first time I encountered a segmentation fault in python and really want to know why it happened. I had dealt with segmentation faults before in C++. But this one really seems way out of league as compared to them!!

Also my code runs perfectly for smaller inputs in descending order. This is happening only when I increase the amount of input.

Comment: There's a reason the [`sys.setrecursionlimit` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) says "This should be done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash." `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000)` is not done with care. If you're running into recursion limit issues, `sys.setrecursionlimit` is rarely the solution - you should change your program to use less stack space.

Comment: Even if Python itself doesn't impose an upper limit on *memory*, your computer does. Computer science is the study of finite systems.